# Is there a way to extend a variables.tf file with another?

Tags: terraform

Just an example scenario would be that I have a module, and that has variables. For example an S3 bucket would need a variable about the name of the bucket.

The `variables.tf` file would look like:

```
variable "bucket_name" { type = string }
```

Now if I want to use that module to create the S3 bucket, and then assign it to a cloudfront distribution, I have to assign the bucket name at that level to the bucket module. For example I want to give the distribution a name, I need to create a `variables.tf` for the distribution with the distribution name defined, but because I use the module of the S3 bucket, I have to include all variables of the S3 bucket as well. So the `variables.tf` file of the distribution would look like:

```
variable "bucket_name" { type = string }
variable "distribution_name" { type = string }
```

If I have a module that is only for `us-east-1`, and it needs the cloudfront distribution, I need to create a `variables.tf` file for that as well containing all the above.

If I for example have multiple AWS accounts for staging, and prod, and want the distribution included in both (or for only one, doesn't matter), I have to create yet another `variables.tf` file containing all the above.

Every time I would add a new variable, I'd have to update at least 4 `variables.tf` files which is definitely not a way (terraform is supposed to reduce hard coding).

What I would like is as I go up the ladder (from s3 to environment module), Import the `variables.tf` file of the "child module", and extend it.

Just for an imaginary scenario, I'd like to:

```
# bucket/variables.tf
variable "bucket_name" { type = string }

# distribution/variables.tf
import_variables {
  source = "../bucket"
}

# us-east-1/variables.tf
import_variables {
  source = "../distribution"
}

# staging/us-east-1/variables.tf
import_variables {
  source = "../../us-east-1"
}
```

Am I having a completely wrong approach to terraform, or I just missed a method with which this variable definition sharing could be done?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Tensorflow (which is the only tag you used).

Comment: You are missing a lot of terraform concepts it seems. One thing to note though is that it is hard to understand what you want to achieve, but as far as I know, no such module exists for importing variables. Additionally, the variables you define at the child module level are always there, so no matter how many times you invoke it, they are there. You can achieve a lot of code portability with a combination of data sources and variable default values though.

Comment: I just don't want to hardcode my infra for every environment, and region. I thought it would be a good idea to define reusable modules that are shared between environments, or regions, and then import them where needed

Comment: I've read your question multiple times and honestly can't understand the problem you are trying to describe. Can you give some examples of things you are hard-coding? I think simply having a lot of sane defaults defined in your variables would go a long way to reducing the issue you are describing.

Comment: It's not about the variable values, but the variable "schema". In the above scenario if I would like to add some settings to the cloudfront distribution, because the modules are 4 levels deep nested, and I want to add the settings at the root level (in .tfvars), I have to update the variables "schema" at each level of nesting, adding the settings to the cloudfront distribution. The reason why I want to define the variables at the root level is because it can be that I want to give different alternative domain names at staging, and prod for example.